# Change text with a transition effect (zoom / fade)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I came across this interesting effect over at http://birvacreativestudio.com/theme/birva200/index.html The one I am talking about is the changing text (Probably the first thing you'll notice)
I got inspector out to see how it was done, but can't figure it out, Is the developer using purse css for this or some sort of mixture with javascript/jQuery?

Could anyone explain to me how to replicate it with jQuery? Are there any plugins/libraries that are good for these type of effects?

Comment: Looks like they are using CSS Animations for the "bounce" effect. Then they use JS to add a class to the currently active text so it bounces in/out. So the animation is done in CSS but the slideshow-ness is done in JS. UPDATE: I think I was looking at the wrong animation, the words that fade in/out are done with CSS Transitions (not Animations) but JS still controls the slideshow-ness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're using [Owl Carousel.](http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/)

See the FadeUp transition here: http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/transitions.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get great text animations easily with this JS animation platform:
http://www.greensock.com/gsap-js/

(just look at the animated header on that page, you'll see what can be done with this + its faster then jQuery animate)